# Python - переносимость приложений

Tags: python, библиотеки

Взял Python в качестве второго языка, в дополнение к Jave. 
Самый неприятный момент, насколько я понял, среда Python начисто лишена простого и красивого способа распространения библиотек/приложений, по аналогии с jar-файлами Java. В последней достаточно наличия интерпретатора на клиентской машине, а библиотеки запросто таскаются вместе с проектом.

С Python в случае зависимостей приложения от конкретных библиотек (а других приложений мало кто пишет) их необходимо компилировать/ставить с готовых сборок, еще и на клиенте. Что мягко говоря не удобно. Либо паковать приложение под конкретную платформу, пользуясь каким-либо инсталлятором: pyInstaller, cx_freeze, py2exe.

В общем, я тут начитался ужасов и багов с этими самыми инсталляторами и прошу подсказать, чем для этих целей пользуется немалое сообщество Python-разработчиков. Интересует простой и проверенный (без костылей и багов) способ собрать портабельное приложение под Win32, начиная Win2k по Win7 (workstation и server).

З.Ы. Jython - не интересует и как вариант не рассматривается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Python стандартным решением является использование [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/). Также удобно работать с [PyInstaller](http://docs.python.org/distutils/).